# NgStyles inside NgFor in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular2-directives, rxjs5

I would like to change the font color depending on some conditions ==> both datas on comming back from observable returning by Http request, I try out theses codes bellow (Typescript+Angular)

```
<td *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">{{user.data.apps.details[0].label}}
          <span [style.color]="user?.data.apps.details[0].state_id as colorId 'green' : 'orange' : 'red'">

</td>
```

"user" is my Observable and "userService" my http service, the datas inside curly braces {{}} are fetch from a Json object

Comment: You probably mean "user**s**" is my Observable" because `user` is only an item from the array emitted by `userService.users`. So what is the question about? What is not working as expected?

Comment: What values is `.state_id` supposed to have? When should the value be `green`, `orange`, or `red`? Your expression is not valid code and it's unclear what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry users and not user... state_id is returning 0, 1 or 2 and I would like to change to change label's color depending on that value

Comment: so ngFor is parsing my Json and returning me a sentance = to "label" then I would apply a color depending from "state_id" who's insinde the Json as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid expression

```
user?.data.apps.details[0].state_id as colorId 'green' : 'orange' : 'red'
```

**update**

This should to what you want if `.state_id` returns `0`, `1`, or `2`:

```
<span [style.color]="['green', 'orange', 'red'][user?.data.apps.details[0].state_id]">
```

Comment: Yes I know Günter I trying to change dynamicly the css apply to the "label" parsing by the ngFor depending on the "state_id"

Comment: I'm not sure what to make from your comment. Does this solve your issue? Or is it not what you were looking for?

Comment: For exemple the following code return label ==> <td *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">{{user.data.apps.details[0].label}}</td>   and the following return my state_id => <td *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">{{user.data.apps.details[0].state_idl}}</td>   and I would like to color my "label" depending on my state_id as 0=green 1=orange and 2=red

Comment: Yes I tried to pass your code instead [style-color]and I doeasn't work...it return any error but the span and the code inside or totally written in the view (and I dont want it I just want it color my td"label"

Comment: I updated the code to contains the whole tag. Is this how you used it?

Comment: No I didn't use it with the last update.. I m trying right now

Comment: No, just replace the 1st code block by the part inside `"..."` in the 2nd code block.

Comment: I treid this out but it returning me a huge error :   
        <td *ngFor="user?.data.apps.details[0].state_id as colorId 'green' : 'orange' : 'red'">{{user.data.apps.details[0].label}}
              <span [style.color]="['green' : 'orange' : 'red'][user?.data.apps.details[0].state_id]"></span>
               
        </td>

Comment: Sorry, but I can't derive what the problem might be from "huge error" ;-) Why do you use `?` after `user`? Can the returned array contain `null` values? What values do you get if you add `{{user?.data.apps.details[0].state_id}}` as content to the `<span>`? You also need to close the `<span>` element.

Comment: I also try that but doasn't work : <td *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">{{user.data.apps.details[0].label}}
              <span [style.color]="['green' : 'orange' : 'red'][user?.data.apps.details[0].state_id]"></span>
               
        </td>

Comment: Then you shouldn't need `?` after `user`

Comment: many thanks for help...for info {{state_id}} return 2 so the color should be red

Comment: And `2` is the only value you get, or are there other values as well? Does the array only contain a single value? If you get an error please post the exact error message.

Comment: No I could get 0 or 1 or 2 as values...see the error bellow   Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td [ERROR ->]*ngFor="user.data.apps.details[0].state_id as colorId 'green' : 'orange' : 'red'">{{user.data.apps.de"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardnextComponent.html@105:12
Parser Error: Unexpected token :, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 66 in [user.data.apps.details[0].state_id as colorId 'green' : 'orange' : 'red'] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardnextComponent.html@105:12 (" <tr>

Comment: But that's not for the code I suggested. That's for the code in your question.

Comment: so I should remove the ngFor?

Comment: The error is about ` [user.data.apps.details[0].state_id as colorId 'green' : 'orange' : 'red'] ` and this part is not in `ngFor` it's what I suggested you should replace with the code from my answer.

Comment: For that code :   <td *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">{{user.data.apps.details[0].label}}
              <span [style.color]="['green' : 'orange' : 'red'][user?.data.apps.details[0].state_id]"></span>
</td>

Comment: zone.js:567 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ] at column 10 in [['green' : 'orange' : 'red'][user.data.apps.details[0].state_id]] in ng:///AppModule/DashboardnextComponent.html@106:20 ("For="let user of userService.users | async">{{user.data.apps.details[0].label}}
              <span [ERROR ->][style.color]="['green' : 'orange' : 'red'][user.data.apps.details[0].state_id]"></span>

Comment: without the ? after "user"

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I forgot to replace `:` by `,`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Now seems like the code is woking got any error in the console but that doesn't color my sentence returned by "label"

Comment: It works ! I put {{user.data.apps.details[0].label}} between the span thank you very much Günter

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work :)